# mysql server fails to install on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, ubuntu-18.04

I am trying to install mysql-server on Ubuntu 18.04. I added `https://dev.mysql.com/get/mysql-apt-config_0.8.15-1_all.deb` as apt repo but when I try to install server I keep getting the below error:

```
update-alternatives: using /etc/mysql/mysql.cnf to provide /etc/mysql/my.cnf (my.cnf) in auto mode
2021-11-03T16:38:17.105736Z 0 [Warning] TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT value is deprecated. Please use --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp server option (see documentation for more details).
2021-11-03T16:38:17.107286Z 0 [ERROR] Could not open file '/var/log/mysql/error.log' for error logging: Permission denied
2021-11-03T16:38:17.107308Z 0 [ERROR] Aborting

dpkg: error processing package mysql-community-server (--configure):
 installed mysql-community-server package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of mysql-server:
 mysql-server depends on mysql-community-server (= 5.7.36-1ubuntu18.04); however:
  Package mysql-community-server is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package mysql-server (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.27-3ubuntu1.4) ...
Processing triggers for systemd (237-3ubuntu10.52) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.8.3-2ubuntu0.1) ...
Processing triggers for ureadahead (0.100.0-21) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 mysql-community-server
 mysql-server
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

What I have already tried following various threads already there:

1. Tried purging/cleaning/removing all mysql packages multiple times. Cleaned up until `dpkg -l` does not list any mysql packages.
2. apt-get dist-upgrade

Comment: `mysql-server depends on mysql-community-server` you shoul install first `mysql-community-server` and then `mysql-server`.

Comment: I have mysql server installed on another ubuntu 18.04  server and I did not install mysql-community-server. `dpkg -l` does not show it either.